# Using some fields in the report to produce another field in the same report

Tags: sql, oracle, report

Suppose I have a table with columns of A, B, and C. I want to produce a report that contains two columns: the first is (A+B), and the second is (A+B)*C - but I don't want to recalculate (A+B), I want to use the first column in the second column in the same report. I use an Oracle DB, thanks in advance.

Comment: Columns, not fields...

Comment: Great! Are you sure there's really a problem with calculation twice?

Comment: In some cases of great reports I want to write shorter code to safe time of processing

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like (this is SQL Server syntax, you didn't specify the DBMS; most DBMS's should work with small changes):

```
select ab, ab * c
from
(
   select a + b ab, c
   from mytable
   where...
) x
```

However, I'm not convinced it will help very much. If the report is too slow I'd suggest looking at improving indexes on the table first, but only if I know I have a problem.

First rule of optimisation: Premature Optimisation is always wrong!